# What's best way to show external text when JavaScript disabled

Tags: external, javascript

I used scripts to load .txt files into a div on my site.  The text files contain html's  `<p>` `<b>` and `<br>`'s  to control they way they look.  I have been racking my brain but have nothing... What's the cleanest/best way to show the data without scripts so visitors can read the file when javascript is disabled.  FYI: I am trying to avoid duplicating the data on additional pages; so ideas other than that would be preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two entirely different things sharing only the first four characters of the name... (well, and some syntax, but it sounded much better without this blurb)

Answer (score 0):

you could include the texts as an IFRAME and replace that with your DIV via Javascript.  The iframe gets displayed no matter what, but if javascript is enabled, you can replace it with more shiny stuff.

Comment: `and replace that with your DIV via Javascript` As Op stated, JS is disabled!

Comment: thats why the iframe. It gets displayed no matter what, but if javasscript is enabled, you can replace it with more shiny stuff.